# Embed html/javascript/css without iframes

Tags: integration

Noob question sorry. We have a number of "apps" that we would like to host/embed in our Sitecore site. They all follow a similar pattern using only frontend html/javascript/css. Is there a simple approach to doing this? Currently we have an app that was developed using just html/javascript/css and subsequently implemented into our site by a third party using a custom page and some C# code. That seems like overkill for our requirements and we really don't want to have to repackage and update our site each time we want to deploy or update an app.

Comment: When you say "host/embed" do you mean you want to embed the "app" in an iFrame on the page itself?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the types of apps you would integrate with your site.  If they are just pure Html/CSS/Javascript functionality you should be able to implement this into Sitecore without having to add additional c# development for each app implementation.

Comment: The apps are specifically for maps that access GIS data using javascript libraries and typically take some input from a textbox and display an appropriate map. We want to host these "apps" inside the Sitecore website rather than open a new browser tab/window.

Answer (score 1):

We have created a component in our previous project which can inject html 
string with inline css & javascript to the page content. Basically html strings are from a 3rd party app which can change based on their design model. We have created some data template fields, especially 'multiline field' which can hold the html string of the 3rd party application & start displaying using @html.Raw(html string here).

Comment: Thanks. I will confess to having some knowledge of SharePoint 2010 and it's possible to add a Content Editor Webpart to a page and reference a file to load into the HTTP response. The HTML produced by SharePoint is generally pretty dreadful but the facility exists. In the example you provide the HTML is loaded as a string into a field rather than referencing a file to load? I was hoping Sitecore might provide a more standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Having done some more research on this, it appears that the [Habitat demo](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki) site contains the functionality that we need in the [Assets module](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/tree/master/src/Foundation/Assets). It allows the Javascript and CSS references to be added in the page definition and then injected in the HTML response.